# Sparsity pattern MarkerFaceColor

Tags: matlab

The MATLAB function `spy` uses the point (`.`) as the default plot marker. This has the disadvantage of unresponsiveness to `MarkerSize` at values less than `5` (i.e., `MarkerSize=1` is identical to `MarkerSize=4`). Therefore, I am plotting `spy` using the plot symbol `o` (circle) instead of `.` (point) because the size of the former can be tuned to sizes in the range `1-4`.

```
spy(bucky,'o',3)
```

The problem is that `MarkerFaceColor` cannot be set in the `LineSpec` properties (to my knowledge), so the result is open circles. Moreover, `spy` does not return an argument such as an object handle. Therefore, changing the marker face color by `set(handle,'MarkerFaceColor','color')` does not work.

Is there a way to set the `MarkerFaceColor` of `spy` plot symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findall` to query the handle to the blue markers and then set the `MarkerFaceColor` property:

```
spy(bucky,'o',3)
markerH = findall(gca,'color','b');
set(markerH,'MarkerFaceColor','r');
```